# Setting up a buildfarm with chroot

Tags: ros, ros2, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

As far as I understand, it's currently not supported to run all roles (master, agent, repo) of a build farm on the same machine.

I thought it might be possible by giving each of them a different chroot environment.

I provide the required folders (/proc, /bin, /usr, ...) in the chroot environment, but /etc is only a copy to avoid conflicts.

When I go into the chroot and run `./reconfigure.bash repo`, everything seems to work (the console output is the same as outside the chroot), but the result seems to be nothing. No `/etc/apache2/sites-available/10-repos.conf` is created, no server running.

Is there something that makes it inherently impossible to run the setup in a chroot?

And is using chroot even a viable choice when trying to run all three roles in the same environment?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330322/setting-up-a-buildfarm-with-chroot/) by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd have to dig in deeper on whether I'd expect chroot's to be enough isolation. There are likely going to be issues with port numbers once you start trying to run things even if the files don't overlap.

I don't think that there's anything inherently impossible, but I'd suggest using VMs instead to get full isolation. The chroot's will be a lot more work as it's something that's never been tested and likely will have corner cases that will need to be figured out.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2019-08-21**:
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Different virtual machines is definitely going to be the more reliable way to run all three build farm roles on one hardware system. I'm pretty sure that chroots alone won't be sufficient unless you're also doing process and network isolation.

I haven't tried to run docker within an lxc/lxd container but if you set up your container permissions sufficiently to allow that you might be able to use lxc/lxd. I'd recommend that over docker containers because docker containers generally don't run a full system complete with init and process supervision, which the buildfarm_deployment expects and essentially requires.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2019-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2019-08-21**:
Thank you!